# <li> inside a <td> with a huge font-size

Tags: html, css

I have been facing a small issue when I add a LI inside a TD element.

The behaviour with small font-size( e.g. 14px), works good, but if I want to use a big font-size (e.g. 60px), the bullet is overflowed the TD element and is being hidden.

The same behaviour doesn't happen with a Div element. How could I fix the bullet and the text, following the same behaviour as a div, inside the TD.

See the code below for a small example.

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}

.tg .tg-0lax{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0!important;
    padding-right: 0!important;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tg-wrap">
  <table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 1</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 2</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 3</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 4</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax" style="font-size: 60px">
        <ul class="ogsmHeight" style="margin-left: 4px;padding-left: 17px;">
            <li class="position-relative extraMenu ">
                    <div style="margin-left: -0.3em">
                          <a class="color-inherit text- position-relative" data-id="297" data-entity="subKpi">
                             <div class="huge-container">
                                <span class="editable text-container border-unset text-">
                                    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet C
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, the HTML is invalid. Only `li` can be direct children of a `ul`.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks good to know Paulie, it can be removed! I will remove from the post also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to remove the inline styles added in `<ul class="ogsmHeight" style="margin-left: 4px;padding-left: 17px;">` and remove the padding from `.tg .tg-0lax` and let the default padding take.

```
.tg .tg-0lax {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```css
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}

.tg .tg-0lax{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tg-wrap">
  <table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 1</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 2</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 3</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 4</th>
      <th class="tg-0lax">column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax" style="font-size: 60px">
        <ul class="ogsmHeight">
            <li class="position-relative extraMenu ">
                    <div style="margin-left: -0.3em">
                          <a class="color-inherit text- position-relative" data-id="297" data-entity="subKpi">
                             <div class="huge-container">
                                <span class="editable text-container border-unset text-">
                                    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet C
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
      <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Subhendu it worked on my end, thank you for help with my mistakes.
I have a question, when we get the font smaller let's say on column 2 we use 14px for font-size, the bullet get it in the middle of the td, there is a way to both be aligned left?

https://codepen.io/guifeliper/full/PLJvMQ